# Why does jQuery dropdown require two clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I click on the button labeled "Continents & Oceans," a dropdown list appears - but only if I click on the button twice. I'd like it to work with the first click.

Is there something wrong with my code, or do I need to add something to make the dropdown drop down on the first click?

This is a jQuery function, but it also includes my first experiment with AJAX, so maybe that's the problem.

```
<input type = "button" id = "konoce" value = "Continents &amp; Oceans" class="btn btn-konoce"
<div id = "div-konoce"> </div>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#konoce").click(function(event) {
    if ($('#div-konoce').html() == '') {
      $.get( "/2b/inc/ajax/db-lists/world/konoce.php", { name: "KonOce"     }, function(data) {
    $('#div-konoce').html(data);
   });
   }
    else {
      $('#div-konoce').html('');
    }
  });            
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I revised my code per the answer below. However, it still takes two clicks to open the dropdown.

```
<button type = "button" id = "konoce" class="btn btn-konoce">Continents &amp; Oceans</button>
<div id = "div-konoce" style="margin: 0 -5px;"> </div>
```

Comment: change this line to the following <div id = "div-konoce" style="margin: 0 -5px;"></div> in your code you are only getting the content if the div is empty - but it has a space character in and so isn't empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line:

```
if ($('#div-konoce').html() == '')
```

checks if the "div-konoce" div is empty, but it's not:

```
<div id = "div-konoce"> </div>
```

There's a space there... meaning not == ''

Remove the space and try again.

Comment: You can also use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

you are not closing your input - it should be:

```
<input type = "button" id = "konoce" value = "Continents &amp; Oceans" class="btn btn-konoce" />
```

and I am not sure why you have this as an input and not a button, since it not used to gather information - but acts as a trigger fo the click.:

```
<button type = "button" id = "konoce" class="btn btn-konoce">Continents &amp; Oceans</button>
```

Comment: I believe the difference between using an input element and a button element is that a button element allows you to put non-text elements on the label. If the label is only intended to be text, I don't think there are any other important differences.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I forgot to close that tag. Thx for the tip about changing it from input to button. I tried marking this as the correct answer, but I don't have enough points yet. The bad news: It still takes two clicks to open the drop down. Maybe there's a bug somewhere else in my code.

Comment: hey - look at Webomatik's answer - you are comparing a non empty div to an empty value - should be fine after that

Answer (score 1):

One tip is ,Why are you always emptying `$('#div-konoce')` , it will cause one ajax request per click . But if you only wrote the first `if` , it will show the previously loaded menu after the first click onwards .

```
 <div id = "div-konoce"></div>
   if ($('#div-konoce').html()=='') {
      $.get( "/2b/inc/ajax/db-lists/world/konoce.php", { name: "KonOce"     }, function(data) {
    $('#div-konoce').html(data);
   });
```